# How to get insert return value using peewee?

Tags: python, peewee, flask-peewee

I use peewee in my project, my table has a filed named is id and it's auto increment and primary key. 
I need to get id value when API insert function is called.
 My Model is

```
class UserModel(pw_db.Model):
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = CharField()
    phone = CharField()
    status = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 't_test'
```

My insert function is

```
def create_user(body=None):
    query = models.UserModel.create(
        username=body['userName'],
        phone=body.get('phone', None),
        status=body.get('status', 1)
    )
    return query
```

The create_user return value could not get id value,
It seems could id using sqlalchemy, I know openstack use sqlalchemy , and their result could get auto_increment id in create function.

Answer (score 1):

Using IntegerField(primary_key=True) is *different* than using PrimaryKeyField (or AutoField in 3.0a). The former is just an integer that acts as pk. The latter is for auto-incrementing.

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#manually-specifying-primary-keys

Answer (score 0):

Solve it.
 Remove fields of id (id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)) in Model, 
would get id value in query.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `id = PrimaryKeyField()`

Answer (score -1):

Tried `query.id` ?

---

`Model.create()` created a new model instance.

The primary key will automatically be retrieved and stored on the model instance.

Comment: query.id is None.

Comment: Is the query executing successfully? Your model class named `UserModel` and you are calling `LoanModel`.

Comment: Yes,  executing successfully. It's generate a new record in db, but query.id is None.

Comment: I try to use    models.UserModel.insert(
        username=body['userName'],   phone=body.get('phone', None),
        status=body.get('status', 1)
    ).execute()  , also is None

Comment: Yes , I uesd execute , new record alreay in db, but return value is None.